# Erro ao passar parametro para proc com dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

Tenho isso dentro de um foreach:

```
parameter.Add("@PROD", item.CDProduto);
parameter.Add("@Filial", item.filial);
parameter.Add("@Cod_Oper", cod_oper);

var result = _connection.ExecuteReader("sp_InsereVenda", parameter, transaction, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

quando eu executo recebo esse erro

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Procedure or function
>   'sp_InsereVenda' expects parameter '@PROD', which was not supplied.

item é a variável de iteração do foreach.

Ao meu ver está tudo correto e não sei o porque do erro acima.

Answer (score 0):

Tudo bem, eu nao uso o @ para passar os parâmetros e sim o :, porém tem que ver o seu sql para entender mesmo, mas segue exemplo abaixo:

```
                #region Sql
            var sql = @" INSERT INTO FIS_GERENCIADOCTOFISCAL (NUMGUID,
                                                    DATMOVIMENTO,
                                                    NUMSEQUENCIAL,
                                                    LOJA,
                                                    NUMTERMINAL,
                                                    NUMORCAMENTO,
                                                    FLGSTATUS,
                                                    FLGOPERACAO,
                                                    DSCRETORNO
                                                   )
                                                VALUES (:NumGuid,
                                                    :DatMovimento,
                                                    :NumSequencial,
                                                    :Loja,
                                                    :CodTerminal,
                                                    :NumOrcamento,
                                                    :FlgStatus,
                                                    :FlgOperacao,
                                                    :DscRetorno
                                                   )";
            #endregion

            #region Parâmetros
            var parameters = new 
            {
                NumGuid = model.NumGuid,
                DatMovimento = model.DatMovimento,
                CodTerminal = model.NumTerminal,
                Loja = model.Loja,
                FlgStatus = model.FlgStatus,
                FlgOperacao = model.FlgOperacao,
                NumOrcamento = model.NumOrcamento,
                NumSequencial = sequence,
                DscRetorno = ""
            };
            #endregion

            return await _dbManager.ExecuteAsync(sql, parameters);
```

O nome dos parametros tem que estar igual ao sql, sem mais e sem menos.

Comment: Matheus, eu uso o Dapper para isso. Essa é a questão.

Comment: Tens como colocar o sql também aqui?